Sampling gain in DCM current mode DC-DC converters
I don't understand why the sampling gain (He(s)) found in the inner loop of current mode converters in CCM is not present in DCM?
I have simulated and compared with the mathematical model the control to output transfer function of an peak current mode control and they match perfectly in DCM if the sampling gain is ignored.
I am unable to demonstrate the sampling gain absence if I analyze the current variation in DCM as in CCM. In CCM I used the same method as in the paper below:
https://ridleyengineering.com/images/current_mode_book/CurrentModeControl.pdf


He(s) that's clearly not only a gain, but some kind of system, which usually is a filter.

Yes, it is approximated with a system with two complex zeros.
He(s) = 1 + s/(Wn*Q) + s^2/Wn^2

so, if you know that it's something that depends on frequency, are you testing whether your DCM current regulation works under time-varying Vc(s)?

The current loop gain includes a pair of RHP zeroes which become a pair of LHP sub-harmonic poles when included in the outer voltage loop gain. The sampling action in the current loop creates these zeroes and I did simulate this gain in an article I published in How2Power. You may also be interested by this PDF on Ridley's model.

Yes, I consider the time-varying Vc(s).
I am working on a small signal model for an average input current mode control using the same method as Mr. Kint proposes in his work. The model works perfectly in CCM. In DCM I couldn't prove mathematically the absence of the RHP - zeroes. Considering that the model is 95% accurate when I ignore the zeroes, I need to investigate if there are alternative methods for analyzing the current loop in DCM and I found very few articles who debate this topic.
Thanks a lot for your help!
